# Xcode Error: PBXCp error: couldn't create directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, j2objc

I want to include a `Messages_de.properties` file in my Xcode project.

I my target's `Build Phase` I did:

![enter image description here][1]

When I try to build the project I get the following errors:

```
PBXCp /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.3-SR1-2/testproject-core/src/main/resources/testproject/core/i18n/Messages_de.properties /Users/mg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bkkczkzivpolszewxttakwlxnztk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testproject.app/testproject/core/i18n/Messages_de.properties
    cd /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.3-SR1-2/testproject
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.3-SR1-2/testproject-core/src/main/resources/testproject/core/i18n/Messages_de.properties /Users/mg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bkkczkzivpolszewxttakwlxnztk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testproject.app/testproject/core/i18n

    error: couldn't create directory /Users/mg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bkkczkzivpolszewxttakwlxnztk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testproject.app/testproject/core/i18n: Not a directoryerror: open /Users/mg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bkkczkzivpolszewxttakwlxnztk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testproject.app/testproject/core/i18n/Messages_de.properties: Not a directory

(null): error: couldn't create directory /Users/mg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bkkczkzivpolszewxttakwlxnztk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testproject.app/testproject/core/i18n: Not a directory

(null): error: open /Users/mg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bkkczkzivpolszewxttakwlxnztk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testproject.app/testproject/core/i18n/Messages_de.properties: Not a directory
```

**What causes these errors and how do I fix them?**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include a directory instead of a file. 
Verify into your code, you probably are using directory manager to manage a file.

Comment: Could you please be more specific I did not understand the answer?